# OnLine vs RealTime

Tags: real-time

What is the different between OnLine and RealTime? Is OnLine = RealTime, but RealTime != Online, or else?

thank you.

Comment: What's the difference between car tire and black hole? Or difference between a watch and Jupiter? You're asking the question without context of what the terms, in your opinion, define.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Online means that there is some kind of interactivity involved, but doesn't enforce limits in latency.

Real-time means that there are limits on latency.

If you move your computer's mouse, you expect the pointer to react immediately and precisely follow your actions. That's real-time. Another example is playing on a music keyboard controller and having some synthesizer program that generates the sounds.

Online, however, is such that your actions show some response in some timely manner, but there's no timely relationship enforced to it. For example, starting a video stream from a (remotely controllable) webcam may show you the pictures with less than 1-second latency, or even up to several minutes, yet be online.

Comment: hi datenwolf, as my understanding, online will take the data from the source, should we call this as a realtime procedure? and how the realtime it self? :) thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You may think it like this: Realtime is Online with hard timing/latency constraints. There's hard realtime, where everything must be in exactly timed fashion down to microsecond accuracy, then there's soft realtime, where things are happening in less than a few milliseconds. And there's Online where things may take their time without known how long exactly, but it will finish in an interactive manner eventually. In contrast to this there's offline processing, where you start a task and have no influence or interactivity until it finishes.

Answer (score 3):

[real-time](/questions/tagged/real-time):

> A task is *real-time* when the *timeliness* of the activities' completion is a functional requirement and correctness condition, rather than merely a performance metric. A real-time system is one where some (though perhaps not all) of the tasks are real-time tasks.

**Online** has a broader meaning and requires a context to be understood correctly. In general case, it's "operational" or "interactive."

Comment: hi GSerg, as know an example from OnLine is ATM machine, if we are in online mode, the data will takes from the main source right (to the bank)? the process getting from main source to the ATM menu monitor, can we call it as realtime? So how we say 'something' is online or realtime? thank you very much for your answer. :)

Comment: @Firdi Your example has very little to do with being real-time or online. You *might* say that an ATM is online because it is connected and ready to work ("operational", from my answer), but it has nothing to do with the data being sent to the server or back to the client.